# Roberts orthogonality and $\alpha$-Isosceles orthogonality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

The definitions of Roberts orthogonality (B D Roberts) and $\alpha$-Isosceles orthogonality (Alonso & Benitez) seems to be identical to me. Can anyone point me out the difference between the two orthogonality?
Thanks in advance.